# How can we write trigger to insert distinct values from one table to another table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Say table1, table2 are 2 tables. Whenever there is an insert/update in the table1, the table2 has to update accordingly.

Please help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: School or work assignment?

Comment: Why do you need to update the table?  Why not just run a query to get the values?

Comment: When you ask how to trigger it: Simply create a "Trigger". If you have troubles with doing this, you can come back and ask a specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MERGE statement. Try something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLE1_AIU
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TABLE1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO TABLE2 t2
      USING (SELECT :NEW.VALUE1 FROM DUAL) n
        ON (t2.VALUE1 = n.VALUE1)
      WHEN NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT (VALUE1)
          VALUES (n.VALUE1);
END;
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
-- insert/update command on table1
create or replace trigger TriggerName before insert or update on table1 for each row
    BEGIN
        -- Write inset/update command on table2
    END;
/
```